# Designing Web Album: CSS or Ajax?

Tags: ajax

I want to design a web album with every image in the album having it's own title, and description. So, at a time only one set of image, title and description would be visible. And on clicking next button, the next set of image, title and description would appear,and so on.

So am wondering, what would be the best way to design with? HTML or AJAX?

I don't want to use the ready to use tools such as lightbox.

Comment: That's like asking: to make my wall prettier, should I use painting or a ladder? AJAX is just a way to get content from a server asynchronously. Once you have the content, you need to display it, with HTML and CSS. Before designing anything, know what you're talking about. Read up on what HTML is, what CSS is, what AJAX is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the browser's back button to work? If so, then you should make your life simple
and use html (since you will only be displaying one image at a time either way).

Ajax implies using html. On the other hand, using html does not necessarily imply that you need to use AJAX to load content dynamically.

What is the purpose of this project? If you are doing it for the learning experience you should go on with AJAX (from scratch). If you want speed and quality use an existing web image gallery. If you need to write it yourself use plain html (or an ajax framework such as dojo, jquery, etc. this will save you a lot of pain solving cross-browser quirks).

In addition, if you want to be able to click a button to take you to the next (previous) image 
and you don't know how many images you will have beforehand, then you are looking for dynamic behavior. You can code dynamic logic either on the client side (javascript), or on the server side (let's say "php" to start with).

Also, how do you plan to keep the corresponding (image, title, description) together?
If you only have a 3 images, say you could hard code each of this into its corresponding html file. eg. 1.html, 2.html, 3.html. Then you would have to point the forward button from a.html to point to b.html. etc...

If you didn't want this boring static behavior and wanted something smarter, say you decided for AJAX. Then you would only have 1.html file and from there (using javascript) you would ask your server for the (image, title, description) and load all that (dynamically, without refreshing the browser) into the same page. The easiest way to get this from the sever is by just reading a a static (XML, or JSON) file which contains all the info (image urls, titles, descriptions). Then with javascript and using DOM manipulation you would remove the old image, and add the new one.

However, this would all be a lot simpler with server-side processing (and it's worth learning). In this case you could have a url which takes a parameter with the image number. eg. http://example.com/gallery/index.php?image=X
then before the server responds to the client with the html, it would realize that you want to load image X so it would get it's corresponding description, title, and url. and "embed" those into the file. Of course, depending on the number, it would also add the right links for the previous and next buttons. Eg. If the currently displaying image was 9 then forward button would "dynamically" be determined to link to (X+1) : http://example.com/gallery/index.php?image=10